# Ошибка при запуске приложения (0xc0000005)

Tags: windows, qt

Всем добрый день. Пару месяцев назад сносил Qt, а теперь снова устанавливаю, но вот незадача - после установки программа стала выдавать ошибку при попытке её открыть. Итак, вот что я уже сделал: перезагрузил компьютер, переустановил программу, сканировал ПК на вирусы, удалил все обновления из Панели управления за последние пару месяцев, почистил реестр, поставил совместимость с windows 7, переустановил винду. Устанавливаю Qt версии 5.14.2, антивирусов не имею. Буду очень признателен за новые советы

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не знаю, что вызывает данную ошибку, но рискну предположить, что возможно надо перестать юзать windows 7 XD... А программе нету багов самой?

Comment: Ещё в январе и полгода до этого всё работало на семёрке как надо. Ломаю голову, что за это время могло поменяться. О каких багах в программе идёт речь? Сама программа даже не запускается, так как сразу вылетает ошибка.